# How to use custom font to design Bottom Navigator

Tags: react-native, user-interface

How do I get to use custom font in React native when designing a Bottom tab navigator?
I have been able to use it on other forms without trouble, but on bottom tab navigator, I still appear to have some challenges with it.

My code looks thus, but it still is the same, Nothing changes.

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomePage from '../src/HomePage';
import TransfersPage from '../src/TransfersPage';
import ProfilesPage from '../src/ProfilePage';
import SettingsPage from '../src/SettingsPage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomNavigation() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        headerShown:false,
        style:{
            fontFamily:'Poppins-Medium',
            fontSize:27,
            color : '#00BB23'
        },
        tabBarIcon:({color, size, focused}) =>{
            let iconName;

            if (route.name ==='HomePage'){
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-home-sharp' : 'ios-home-outline'
            }else if(route.name ==='Transfers'){
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-send-sharp' : 'ios-send-outline'
            }else if(route.name ==='Profile'){
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-person-sharp' : 'ios-person-outline'
            }else if(route.name ==='Settings'){
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-settings-sharp' : 'ios-settings-outline'
            }

            return <Icon name={iconName} size={27} color={"#00BB23"} />
        }
    })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Transfers" component={TransfersPage} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfilesPage} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsPage} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default BottomNavigation;
```

And my app.Js looks like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SplashScreen from './src/SplashScreen';
import LoginPage from './src/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './src/RegisterPage';
import BottomNavigation from './navigation/BottomNavigation';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={BottomNavigation} options={{headerShown:false}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Is there something i am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Tab.Screen
    options={() => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View
          style={[
            styles.usContainer,
            { borderColor: focused ? colors.primary : colors.white },
          ]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.usText,
              { color: focused ? colors.primary : colors.white },
            ]}>
            US
          </Text>
        </View>
      ),
    })}
    name="us-screen"
    component={Demo}
  />
```

you can use your custom component like that